# Create figure with data from geopandas [Python]

Tags: python, figure, subplot, geopandas

my goal is to create 4 subplots within one figure. The singular plots constist of geodata, which I gained from geojson-files. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geojson
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from geojson import Point

ags = gpd.read_file('150824-altglascontainer-mannheim.geojson')
hts = gpd.read_file('standorte_hts_gesamt.geojson')
wlan = gpd.read_file('standorte-wlan-mit-geocode.geojson')
akc = gpd.read_file('150824-altkleidercontainer-mannheim.geojson')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)   #top left
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)   #top right
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)   #bottom left
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)   #bottom right
```

In this way, nothing happens (which makes sense to me). Unfortunately, I often got the error message "unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'".

Do you have a way to help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you out without having the data? Your problem appears to be in `gpd.read_file`. Give us a way to reproduce the error (minimum working example) and maybe someone can figure out what's wrong. Or maybe you'll even find it yourself.

Comment: Also, you don't have any code that is actually plotting. After creating the figure, you need to plot something on it. Eg `ags.plot(ax=ax1)`